# Multiple Autocomplete with a value of a list of strings can't generate Converter JSF?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am currently working on a project and I need tags for questions (like the stackoverflow tags) so I am using a multiple autocomplete (it is an `h:form`):

```
<p:autoComplete id="autoComplete" value="#{questionMB.tags}" completeMethod="#{questionMB.complete}" multiple="true" forceSelection="true" unique="true" />
```

This is the `questionMB`

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
@RolesAllowed(value = { "ADMIN", "SUPERUSER", "USER" })
public class questionMB implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4130025302903207410L;
    private List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();
    //other vars...

    public List<String> complete(String query) {
        //retrieves data from database
        return DBHelper.completeTag(query);
    }

    //other functions, getters and setter...
}
```

When I am using this it throws this Exception:

```
20:47:21,418 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-8) Error Rendering View[/user/postRepair.xhtml]: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.faces.cdi.CdiUtils.createConverter(CdiUtils.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.InstanceFactory.createConverter(InstanceFactory.java:481)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createConverter(ApplicationImpl.java:510)
at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.createConverter(ApplicationWrapper.java:431)
at org.omnifaces.cdi.converter.ConverterManager.createConverter(ConverterManager.java:155)
at org.omnifaces.cdi.converter.ConverterManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.createConverter(Unknown Source)
at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplication.createConverter(OmniApplication.java:98)
at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getConverter(ComponentUtils.java:175)
at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeSuggestions(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:481)
at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeResults(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:136)
at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeEnd(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:117)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:595)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1654)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:615)
at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:159)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1456)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:355)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:400)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:319)
at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:63)
at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:228)
at org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContext.processPartial(OmniPartialViewContext.java:122)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1101)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1647)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:442)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:170)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.omnifaces.viewhandler.OmniViewHandler.renderView(OmniViewHandler.java:115)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:199)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:708)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
at org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter.doFilter(GzipResponseFilter.java:181)
at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at com.github.adminfaces.template.session.AdminFilter.doFilter(AdminFilter.java:128)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:55)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jaspi.JASPICSecureResponseHandler.handleRequest(JASPICSecureResponseHandler.java:48)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

There is no problem with anything else because when I remove the `value="#{questionMB.tags}"` it works completely fine, so I can remove, add and search for tags. But when I add the value: I enter one character (the `DBHelper.completeTag()` still works correct and returns values which are just not shown in the UI) and the exception is thrown.

So the problem seems to be that no converter can be generated (just see line 2 in stacktrace). So I thought it should be no problem converting it because I am only using strings. Maybe there is a problem with the list and it cannot be converted. So I searched for two days and I could not find a single problem that can answer mine.

**EDIT**

I already tested which components are null: `DBHelper.completeTag()` returns a fine list of strings with the correct value from the Database. `List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();` initializes the list of tags but with no String values (not null).

I am using Primefaces 7.0, OmniFaces 3.2, Mojarra  and Primefaces-Extensions 6.1.1.

Comment: What is your PF version? Does it fail entering the first tag too?

Comment: And you can debug the jsf code and set a breakpoint to see what exactly is null

Comment: And what are the Mojarra and Omnifaces versions?

Comment: @Selaron I edited the question to answer your questions

Comment: Also you are using PF 7.0 with PFE 6.1.1 that is a mismatch you should upgrade to PFE 7.0.2 which goes with PF 7.0.   `

Comment: @Kukeltje I edited the question to answer your questions

Comment: @Melloware thanks, I will do it but I don't think it will solve the problem

Comment: debug and set a breakpoint....

Comment: @fuggerjaki61 you did not yet add the Mojarra version

Comment: @Kukeltje where should I set it?

Comment: Uhhhh..... in your IDE?

Comment: related?: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/4500 ('workaround is to install omnifaces 3.3) And posting the error and stacktrace in google gave me this result.

Comment: @Kukeltje I googled the error with the stacktrace, too (for some hours) but nothing like this was shown to me so the answers of the google search engine may vary within other countries or search history. Please do not insult me not googling it because I've done it for a long time before I decided to post this question. (this is no insult)

Comment: You did not state (like requested in [ask]) that you searched and yes, it might vary, but next time state that you searched with things like this. Unless otherwise mentioned, I assume things are not done (and that is most of the time correct). And things are not insult, just suggestions... (If I wanted to insult I'd use words like W*F etc ;-).... I now even used 'please'... and 'next time')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As found out by @Kukeltje, this is a known issue: [NPE when determining converter for primitive values](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/4500).

The workaround is said to be [installing omnifaces 3.3](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/4500#issuecomment-435720773).

The actual fix is scheduled for Mojarra 2.3.10 release - the reference implementation of Jakarta Faces.

---

*Yesterday I suggested in a comment someone should write **this** answer but the comment was deleted, so here I go dispite the fact this is not my finding. Feel free to write another answer, this is not ment for reputation harvesting but a signpost for others encountering this issue. While madly one gets no feedback for deleted comments, I guess it was deleted because I hintet that the OP is surely not using Version 8 of Mojarra in a sarcastic way. Sorry if someone felt offended.*

Comment: Yes, same with some usefull links with a becau.se domain. Content is useful, link should mabe be different. But it IS the reason you downvoted and OP only gets hints after closing or too much downvotes so SO forces me to write text each time. Not very friendly of SO to people who are trying to help. But I'm fine with your answer (I did not try, just hinted, so I was not 100% sure and hence no answer). But the thing is String is not a primitive... So that made me doubt. I commented there (on my 'other' git account: open-gdsn)

Comment: @Kukeltje Thats true. Are you also sometimes wired like "Isn't this the post where I wrote a comment? Did I actually write a comment anywhere?" ^^